# Default.png - en-gb / Worldworld Localization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, localization

Is it possible to have 1 Default.png(@2x) for en_GB and a 1 for all the rest of the countries.

I have tried to do this this morning:

1/ Added the files / grouped then and selected "English - United Kingdom" as their localization

2/ Added the other Default.png(@2x) and did not select a localization on them

But when I build for a phone that is English - United Kingdom it is showing the Default.png(@2x) that did not have localisation set.

I really hope this is possible and I don't have to add all languages and do it that way!

Please advise.

Thanks
-JM

Comment: Just checking, but "Default.png(@2x)" isn't your exact file name right?

Comment: No, I was just trying to say I also have the @2x version also. Sorry if this was confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by selecting your image in Xcode and on the right side file inspector clicking the "+" to add a localization to the image.

[image]

Comment: This is what I did and set the localization as "English - United Kingdom" on one set of the default.png's and did not set any localization on the other and it did not work.